# JavaScript redirect with port number with url_for('views.home')

Tags: javascript, flask

Here is my entire 404.html page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Page Not Found{% endblock title %}
{% block head %}
  <script>
  var seconds =7;
// countdown timer.

var url="{{url_for('views.home')}}";
// variable for index.html url - NEEDS PORT NUMBER

function redirect(){
 if (seconds <=0){

 // redirect to new url after counter  down.
  window.location = url;
 } else {
  seconds--;
  document.getElementById("pageInfo").innerHTML="Redirecting to Home Page after "
+seconds+" seconds."
  setTimeout("redirect()", 1000)
 }
}
</script>

{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}
<header><h1>Sorry, the Page was not Found</h1></header>

<h1>Oops! Looks like the page doesn't exist anymore</h1>
  <a href="{{ url_for('views.home') }}"><p>Click Here</a>To go to the Home Page</p> Needs port Number for link

<!-- IE needs 512+ bytes: https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ieinternals/friendly-http-error-pages -->
{% endblock content %}
{% block body %}
 <body onload="redirect()">
<p id="pageInfo"></p>
{% endblock body %}
```

The problem occurs when the web server is running on port 5000. The redirect uses to port 80. I do not know how to use javascript to redirect to  specific port number. Everything else seems to work fine. I need the port number to be used dynamically; the port number may change so I do not want to hard code the port number to the url variable. If there is something else I am missing please don't hesitate to make an comment or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to build up the url with some js

`window.location.origin`
Will give you host+port something like `http://localhost:3000` or whatever port/host you are running on.

So you can prepend that to your `{{url_for('views.home')}}` to get a correct url.

Im not sure what the value of your  `url="{{url_for('views.home')}}";` is so you may need to add an extra `/` in to make it work.

Comment: The problem with window.location.origin is that I need the port number not the url with the port number. url_for('views.home') returns http://127.0.0.1/ (it has the forward slash). It would work to add the port number in javascript if the visitor has javascript enabled. If they have disabled javascript they must click the "Click HereTo go to the Home Page" link which also needs the port number for the link.

Comment: location.port will be just the port. Not entirely sure of your application but hope it helps